# Does the "Conquest of Jerusalem" triggered modifier still exist?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In past versions of EU4, occupying Jerusalem (the province Judea) could activate a [triggered modifier](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Triggered_modifiers) granting some bonuses (yearly prestige and some missionary-related stuff).

The listing for this triggered modifier was recently removed from the wiki between [these](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/index.php?title=Triggered_modifiers&oldid=105633) [two](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/index.php?title=Triggered_modifiers&oldid=105643) page revisions.  Does this indicate that the triggered modifier was removed, or is it just an error in the wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer listed under the triggered modifiers, however you do still get the bonuses. They show up if you hover over your missionaries or prestige. Note that according to the wiki, these bonuses only apply if you are Christian, Muslim, or Jewish. (see [the page on missionaries](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Envoy#Missionary) and [the page on prestige](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Prestige#Increasing_prestige) for bonuses for other religions). As far as I know, there is no longer a place in-game to see provincial religious bonuses.

Comment: There is an ingame place to see the bonus, i can't make the print screen here, but it's in province modifiers icons (where you get info about zealot zeal for example)